# How to remove multiple XML declarations and closing tags after merging XML files?

Tags: xml, xslt

The main xml file consists of a number of XML files that have been inserted one below the other. All files have the same structure. However, the inserted files still have their original declarations, opening and closing tags. This situation creates an error at a later stage. How can XSLT remove the superfluous declarations, opening and closing tags in the middle of the file?

The main file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIBDB><GROUP><A>
<-- xml data 1 -->    
</A></GROUP></BIBDB>    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIBDB><GROUP><A>
<-- xml data 2 -->
</A></GROUP></BIBDB>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIBDB><GROUP><A>
<-- xml data 3 -->
</A></GROUP></BIBDB>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIBDB><GROUP><A>
<-- xml data 1 -->    
</A>

<A>
<-- xml data 2 -->
</A>

<A>
<-- xml data 3 -->
</A></GROUP></BIBDB>
```

Comment: Consider to do the merging with XSLT and that way ensure you have a well-formed document.

Comment: @Martin The files are merged elsewhere using a batch file, I'm told. I can't change that. The desired xslt should do the job in one go...

Comment: XSLT takes XML as input and the result zour batch file produces is not XML so don't expect to be able to use XSLT to fix that concatenation of several XML documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've created your main file in that manner, you've lost the ability to use any tool based upon a compliant XML parser because your main file is simply not XML.

Well-formed XML cannot have multiple root elements.  It also cannot have multiple XML declarations (or XML declarations anywhere other than at the top of the file).

So, your options are:

1. Backup, as Martin Honnen mentions in the comments, and re-compose
   your original (presumably well-formed) XML documents via compliant
   XML tools such as XSLT.
2. Process your file as text, not XML, and repair the problems
   preventing it from being well-formed XML.   This is not going to be
   easy, especially in the general case, but for sufficiently narrow
   constraints which may apply in any specific case, you might be able
   to achieve a brittle success in this manner.

I strongly recommend #1 over #2.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation and suggestions. I'll try the options you mentioned.